# Condition number of a transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

> Does the condition number of matrix $A^T$ equal to the condition
>   number of matrix $A$?

The condition number of a matrix is $||A|| \cdot ||A^{-1}||$.

Comment: What is the "condition number" of a matrix? Is it $cond(A)=||A||\cdot ||A||^{-1}$?

Comment: It depends on the matrix norm used in the definition of the condition number.

Answer (score 1):

A general proof that works even for the case when $A$ is a rectangular matrix is stated below for interest.

Suppose that $A$ is any real $m \times n$ matrix.

When the rank of $A$ is full, then we can define the condition number of $A$ (in $2$-norm or *spectral norm*) as
$$
\kappa(A) = {\sigma_{\max}(A) \over \sigma_{\min}(A)}
$$

Suppose that the singular value decomposition of $A$ is given as
$$
A = U S V^T
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices.

Then it follows that
$$
A^T = V S^T U^T
$$

Thus, it follows that the singular values of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same.

Consequently, it follows that
$$
\sigma_{\max}(A^T) = \sigma_{\max}(A)
$$
and
$$
\sigma_{\min}(A^T) = \sigma_{\min}(A)
$$

Hence, it is immediate that
$$
\kappa(A^T) = \kappa(A)
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is true. Note that for every square matrix $A$ we have $\|A\| = \|A^\intercal\|$. Hence,

\begin{align}
\kappa(A^\intercal) &= \| A^\intercal \| \| (A^\intercal)^{-1} \| \\
&= \| A^\intercal \| \| (A^{-1})^\intercal \| \\
&= \| A \| \| A^{-1} \| \\
&= \kappa(A).
\end{align}

Comment: What about a rectangular matrix? Not a square one? Can't we calculate the condition number for a rectangular matrix?

Comment: We can, but your given definition of the condition number implies that $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: I am using np.linalg.cond with p=2 from numpy.

Comment: This does not matter. You have to explain how you define the condition number for non-invertible matrices. Otherwise, my answer is suitable for your question and you should think about accepting it or tell me what is still not clear.